# anyone know how to use a partially applied three argument function infix (haskell)

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, partial-application

I want to apply a 3 argument function in different ways based on a boolean value (one of the arguments).

I'd like to be able to apply it in an infix manner so I can chain it (example below). something like the following but that actually works.

```
f :: Bool -> a -> a -> a

f True  i j = i
f False i j = j

... y `(f True)` z `(f False)` b
```

Do I need to have the Bool as the second variable? Or something else? I'm kind of lost.

P.S. the reason I wanted to do this was to have optional append function

Comment: why not define two functions ftrue and ffalse and use them? (I agree this wouldn't work in the more general case though...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [infix notation for functions with more than two arguments](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Infix_operator#Using_prefix_functions_with_infix_notation) is possible but not very nice. In your case, given

```
f :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
f True i j = i
f False i j = j
```

you can write

```
(True `f` 1) 3
```

It's much easier (as suggested by others) to write:

```
let ft = f True
let ff = f False
```

then you can do

```
1 `ft` 3 `ff` 5
```

If you want to use `f` you should write:

```
(False `f` ((True `f` 1) 3)) 5
```

You can verify that

```
1 `ft` 3 `ff` 5 == (False `f` ((True `f` 1) 3)) 5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a reverse application operator to achieve a similar effect. However, for every operator fixity you will have to define its own pair of operators.

This works:

```
infixl 5 -|
(-|) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(-|) = flip ($)

infixl 5 |-
(|-) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
(|-) = ($)

infixr 5 =|
(|=) :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> (a -> c)
(|=) = flip

infixr 5 |=
(=|) :: a -> (a -> c) -> c
(=|) = (-|)

f b x y = if b then x else y

main = do
    putStrLn $ "qwe" -| f True |- "asd" -| f False |- "kojo"
    putStrLn $ "qwe" =| f True |= "asd" =| f False |= "kojo"
```

And prints:

```
kojo
qwe
```

Here `-|` and `|-` brackets enclose left-associative infix expressions and `=|` and `|=` enclose right-associative expressions.

Be wary that as those are just pairs of independent operators, error messages when misusing them may be quite obscure.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed until now that `$` is a specialisation of `id`.

Answer (score 3):

While [infix expression syntax](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Infix_expressions) have been proposed, they have not been adopted, to the best of my knowledge.

You might consider using `if then else` ternary functions, like so:

```
infix 0 ?
(?) :: Bool -> (t, t) -> t
c ? (t, e) = if c then t else e
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, `f` would have type `f :: Bool -> a -> a -> a`

See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Infix_operator#Using_prefix_functions_with_infix_notation for more information on using prefix functions in an infix setting.

Hopefully somebody else is wiser and can explain why

```
1 `f True` 3
```

doesn't work, since

```
ft = f True
1 `ft` 3
```

works fine, and this seems to violate referential transparency...

It would seem that there isn't a "nice", easy way to do this, but I'm sure there's some higher level pattern that this fits, or you could do something with, e.g., `zipWith` or folds...

Comment: `f True` is not allowed because it's syntactically not allowed by the Haskell98 report. http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#operators see section 3.2, the infix operators are also defined on "id"s which are single names like "f" whereas "f True" would be an expression

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the boolean function at all? If the value is never used, why not define f as

```
f :: a -> a -> a  
f i j  
i `f` j
```

If the boolean is really needed, then as Pvital suggested, create a ftrue and ffalse and use those.

Comment: The boolean is used to choose whether the value is the first parameter or the second.

Comment: @tredontho Ah right, I didn't pay that close attention to the definition of f. :)